# How do I control the font of the item text in an enumitem list?

Tags: lists, fontsize, enumitem

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{description}[style=nextline]
\item[Label 1] {\sffamily\LARGE item text 1}

\item[Label2] Item text 2
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

My issue is that I would like `\LARGE` to change the size of the item text but not the label. I know I can control the label with `font=<commands>`. Is there a smart way to control the item text?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,color}
\begin{document}

\begin{description}[style=nextline,before=\color{red}\Huge,font=\normalsize]
\item[Label 1] Item text 1
\item[Label2] Item text 2
\end{description}
some text
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

Would something like the following be what you want?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{description}[style=nextline,font=\normalfont\normalsize]
    \sffamily\LARGE
    \item[Label 1] item text 1
    \item[Label2] Item text 2
\end{description}
```

[image: result]

Comment: One has to explicit set the font size of the label in order for it not to get overwritten by a size set between the begin and end of the environment.

Comment: @Oliver: One has to do this in my solution too. Actually there is not much difference between my solution and Caramdirs. Mine looks perhaps a bit more elegant as the font command is also in the optional argument.